# Flex size items inside container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with 3 dives with content inside them.

```
item1 = 50%
item2 = should shrink according to the left over space. 
item3 = 33%
```

I'm trying to get item2 to shrink to the left over space.

```
I was using width = min-content on item2 but this doesn't work in IE11
```

So I'm trying to find a way to make this work.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.item2 {
  width: auto;
}

.item3 {
  width: 33%;
}
```

I tried using flex-shrink but not fully understanding if that will help in IE. If item3 is not in the container then item2 should take up the other 50%.

Comment: Can you post a working demo of your problem?

Comment: Never mind I'm stupid I was adding in another value that was screwing everything up. Working now. Thanks for the reply.